# How to Compress audio float[] data in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio, compression, byte

I'm trying to make a proximity voice chat on a multiplayer game. but when I send the audio data as float[] through the network it has a really big packet size and sometimes packets fail.

I have already tried compressing floats as bytes, but trust me it was really noisy:

```
   public static byte[] ConvertAudioClipToByteArray(float[] data)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[data.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            bytes[i] = (byte)(data[i] * 255f);
        }

        return bytes;
    }

    public static float[] ConvertByteArrayToAudioClip(byte[] bytes)
    {
        float[] samples = new float[bytes.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
        {
            samples[i] = (float)bytes[i] / 255f;
        }

        return samples;
    }
```

and also I tried this algorithm from a website but it doesnt work for some reason:

```
    public static byte[] Compress(float[] data, float threshold)
    {
        List<byte> compressedData = new List<byte>();
        int lastNonZeroIndex = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Mathf.Abs(data[i]) < threshold)
            {
                compressedData.Add(0);
            }
            else
            {
                for (int j = lastNonZeroIndex + 1; j <= i; j++)
                {
                    compressedData.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(data[j]));
                }
                lastNonZeroIndex = i;
            }
        }

        return compressedData.ToArray();
    }

    public static float[] Decompress(byte[] compressedData)
    {
        List<float> data = new List<float>();
        int i = 0;

        while (i < compressedData.Length)
        {
            if (compressedData[i] == 0)
            {
                data.Add(0);
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                float value = BitConverter.ToSingle(compressedData, i);
                data.Add(value);
                i += 4;
            }
        }

        return data.ToArray();
    }
```

I was expecting a soft voice that has a small size in bytes.

Comment: Is this audio being generated on the fly? If not it would be best to have each client have the asset already and just play it.

Comment: no that is for proximity voice chat @RetiredNinja

Comment: you will never be able to achieve something efficient this way. you need a VoIP plugin such as https://github.com/adrenak/UniVoice